# is % operator and format method consistent?

Tags: format, python-3.5

Seems in this particular instance the % operator and format method a bit inconsistent. Much more probable though is that I just don't comprehend the way the % operator works as it does.

```
>>> '{!r}'.format((1,2))
'(1, 2)'
```

why the following is error?

```
>>> '%r' % (1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>>
```

Wouldn't it be more consistent the the both produce the same result?

Below is my original question which I ask you to disregard.

```
What’s wrong with the following snippet?

    >>> '%r' % (1,2),{'a':10,'b':20}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

While 

     >>> '%r' % 'foo',(1,2),{'a':10,'b':20}
    ("'foo'", (1, 2), {'a': 10, 'b': 20})

works.
what is so magical about ‘foo’ here, besides the

    >>> '{!r}'.format(((1,2), {'a':10,'b':20}))
    "((1, 2), {'a': 10, 'b': 20})"

works.
```

Comment: The old-style equivalent of `"{!r}".format((1, 2))` is `"%r" % ((1, 2),)`, which works just fine.

Comment: It works. Yet, I'm still confused. What type of object '%r' shall get to print '(1,2)' ?

Comment: So the interpolation operator `%` takes two operands, a string and a tuple (it can take a dict instead of a tuple, but that's beside the point).  The tuple must be the same length as the number of format specifications in the string.  In the case of a single format specifier, you may instead provide a single *non-tuple* operand.  So what's going on here is that you're providing a tuple to be placed in the only available slot, and that is being interpreted as you providing a tuple of objects to be interpolated into the string.  `((1, 2),)` is a tuple of length one, containing only `(1, 2)`

Comment: Your explanation made it clear to me. Appreciated.